# How is the matrix A related to the lattice space L in SIS?

Tags: lattice-crypto, hardness-assumptions, sis

Is the matrix **$A= (b_1|,...,|b_m)$** where **B**=$(b_1,...,b_m)$ is the basis of the lattice space, $L$(**B**)? Not sure if the answer is trivial however I'm having trouble seeing how SIS is a lattice hard problem when it's definition doesn't seem to include a lattice.

Following this, the restriction on the the vector **$x$** $\leq \beta$. Where does $\beta$ come from? I understand by restricting the value of $\beta$ you increase the hardness of the problem but at what point do you is it defined?

Answer (score 5):

### About the basis

As stated in the other answer, the lattice directly related to SIS is actually the $q$-ary lattice defined as

$$\mathcal{L}_q^\bot(A) := \{ u \in \mathbb{Z}^n : Au = 0 \mod q \}.$$

And its basis is not the matrix $A$. To construct a basis to this lattice, one usually suppose that $A$ has $n$ linearly independent columns (let's say, the first $n$) and write $A = [A_1 \quad A_2]$ with $A_1$ being an $n\times n$ matrix invertible over $\mathbb{Z}_q$, then the following matrix $B$ is a basis:

$$
B =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    ~q\cdot I_n~  & -A_1^{-1}A_2 \\
    ~\vec 0~  & I_{m-n}
    \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times m}
$$

### About the hardness

Actually, it could be a hard problem regardless its connections with lattice problems. But it is connect to lattices in several ways. First, it is obvious that finding short vectors in $\mathcal{L}_q^\bot(A)$ gives us solutions to SIS. Moreover, it has been proved that if one can solve SIS in polynomial time in average, then one can solve hard lattice problems.

Roughly speaking: if you had an algorithm to solve SIS with non-negligible probability (for instance, your algorithm could work one time out of one million), then you would have an algorithm to solve approximate versions of [GapSVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#GapSVP) and [SIVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Shortest_independent_vectors_problem_(SIVP))).

### About the value $\beta$

The value $\beta$ is a parameter of the problem. It is easy to find $u$ such that $Au = 0 \mod q$ (just use Gaussian elimination), what may be hard is to find a short vector satisfying this equation. But how do you define short? Using $\beta$ as an upper bound to the length.

These are standard facts: if $\beta \ge q$, then $u = (q, 0, 0,..., 0)$ is a valid solution, therefore, SIS is trivial for such values of $\beta$. If $\beta$ is too small, then maybe there is no valid solution. If $\beta \ge \sqrt{m}$ and $m \ge n\log q$, then it is guarantee that there exist at least one valid solution.

Comment: The dimension of $u$ seems to be $m$.

Answer (score 3):

If you are solving a SIS instance $As = 0$ over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ then this can be seen as finding a short non-zero vector from the lattice $\{z \in \mathbb{Z}^m \ \mid Az = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n\} \supset q \mathbb{Z}^m$. Thus it is not the same as your $L(B)$.

On the other hand, showing that SIS is as hard as certain lattice problems is not obvious and follows from [this work](https://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/~dmst/teaching/SS2018/Ajtai96.pdf) and a long sequence of works establishing progressively stronger
results about the hardness of the SIS. You can find some general information in [this survey](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lattice-survey.pdf).